# Liquid Template encoding issue with spring boot version 2.0.5

Tags: spring-boot, liquid

I am using Spring Boot version 2.0.5. and liquid template version 0.7.8

My problem is when I am using German text in the template file and when sending mail then few German characters converted into ? mark.

So what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the path from the text file template, through processing and sending out as an email the character encoding is being mangled, so that the German characters, encoded in one scheme, are being incorrectly rendered as the wrong "glyph" in the other scheme, in the email.

The first things to check are what the encoding is for the template file. Then investigate how the email is being rendered. For example if it is an HTML email see if there is a character encoding reference in the header with a different encoding, e.g.:

```
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
```

If this differs from the encoding of the file, e.g. ISO-8859-1, then the first thing I would try is to resave the template in UTF-8, you should be able to do that within most IDEs or advanced text editors such as Notepad++

(As the glyphs are question marks it may be that the template is UTF-8 or UTF-16 and the HTML is in a more limited charset.)

If that doesn't work then you may need to look at your code and pay attention to how the raw bytes from the template are converted to Strings. For example:

```
String template = new String(bytesFromFile);
```

Would use the system default Charset, which might be different from the file. The safe way to convert the bytes to the String is to specify the character set:

```
String template = new String(bytesFromFile, "UTF-8");
```